# Query that returns similar and different rows from two tables that dont have relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with multiple columns but I only care about two columns (profile1 and profile2). Neither table has a relationship to the other.
I would like to see if

- profile1 and profile2 both exist in both table1 and table2
- profile1 and profile2 both exist in table1 but not in table2
- profile1 and profile2 both exist in table2 but not in table1

table 1

```
profile1 profile2
```

table 2

```
profile1 profile2
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

profile1 and profile2 both exist in table1 and table2

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.profile1, T2.profile2
    FROM table2 as T2
WHERE  EXISTS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.profile, T1.profile2
FROM table1 as T1

    WHERE T2.profcode = T1.profcode 
    AND T2.connecting_profcode = T1.connecting_profcode
);
```

Exists in T1 but not in T2

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.profile1, T2.profile2
    FROM table2 as T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DISTINCT T1.profile1, T1.profile2
FROM table1 as T1

    WHERE T2.profile1 = T1.profile1 
    AND T2.profile2 = T1.profile2
);
```

Exists in T2 but not in T1

```
SELECT  DISTINCT T1.profile1, T1.profile2
FROM table1 as T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T2.profile1, T2.profile2
    FROM table2 as T2
    WHERE T1.profile1 = T2.profile1 
    AND T1.profile2 = T2.profile2
);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  This sentence "I want to see the similarities and differences between each table based on just profile1 and profile2" is open to wide interpretation.

Comment: Sorry. I updated my OP does it make sense now?

Comment: You can't use `DISTINCT DISTINCT`. Just one of them.

Comment: There's also no need for `DISTINCT` when you're using a subquery in `EXISTS`. Either it exists or it doesn't, it doesn't matter how many of them there are.

Comment: you can use joins to get the desired results. in order to apply joins relationship between two tables is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You want separate `SELECT` statement

1.profile1 and profile2 both exist in both table1 and table2

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 where profile1 = t1.profile1 and profile2 = t1.profile2);
```

2.profile1 and profile2 both exist in table1 but not in table2

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where profile1 = t1.profile1 and profile2 = t1.profile2);
```

3.profile1 and profile2 both exist in table2 but not in table1

```
select t2.* 
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 where profile1 = t2.profile1 and profile2 = t2.profile2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
Select  
*,
ExistsInT1= Case when t2p1 is NULL AND t1p1 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end,
ExistsInT2= Case when t1p1 is NULL AND t2p1 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end,
ExistsInBoth= Case when t1p1 IS NOT NULL AND t2p1 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end
from (


    select t1.Profile1 as T1P1, t1.Profile2 as T1P2, T2.profile1 as T2p1,
t2.profile2 as t2p2 from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2
    on t1.profile1=t2.profile1 and t2.profile2=t1.profile2
union 
     select t1.Profile1 as T1P1, t1.Profile2 as T1P2, T2.profile1 as T2p1,
t2.profile2 as t2p2  from table1 t1 right outer join table2 t2
    on t1.profile1=t2.profile1 and t2.profile2=t1.profile2
) T
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error near `full outer join table t2`

Comment: I misread the tag as sql server. Updated my answer for my sql

Comment: @derrickrozay Were you able to try out the updated Query?